# Foreach loop through Gravity Forms entries

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

So, I'm trying to iterate through a foreach loop of all the entries to a gravity forms form. I have it sort of working in a template, but I need to put it in a class (creating a calendar and need to pull in entry information) and now it is just iterating over the last entry a bunch of times. Not sure where I went wrong:

```
    $form_id = 9; //Enter the form ID here. The PTO form ID is 9;
    $search_criteria = array();
    $sorting         = array();
    $paging          = array( 'offset' => 0, 'page_size' => 25 );
    $total_count     = 0;
    $entry           = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging, $total_count );   

    foreach ( $entry as $entries ) {

        $entry_id     = rgar( $entries, 'id' );
        $fname        = rgar( $entries, '13.3' );
        $lname        = rgar( $entries, '13.6' );
        $pto_start    = rgar( $entries, '1' );
        $pto_end      = rgar( $entries, '3' );
        $e_location   = rgar( $entries, '16' );
        $pto_approval = rgar( $entries, '15' );


        $supervisor_location = um_user('employee_location');


        if ( ($supervisor_location === 'Elk City, OK') && ($e_location === 'Elk City, OK' ) ) { 
            if ( $pto_start != $this->currentDate ) {
                return '<div id="'.$this->currentDate.'" class="day '.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
                    ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'">'.$cellContent.'</div>';
            }
            elseif ( $pto_start == $this->currentDate ) {
                return '<div id="'.$this->currentDate.'" class="day has-pto '.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
                    ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'">'.$cellContent.'<div class="inner-pto-cal '.lcfirst($pto_approval).'">'.$fname. ' '.$lname.'</div></div>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how relevant the answer is now, but it might help someone in future.

1. It would be advisable to switch `$entries` and `$entry`. It's quite confusing that you use `$entries` for singular entry and `$entry` for an array of entries.
2. Define what output you are looking for. You are looking to get an array, but you're rewriting your values with each loop - that's why the last one stands- like you're repainting a house and wondering why only the top color can be seen...
3. I'd say you want to do this to the `$calendar_data` array and an `$outputx` output:

   ```
   $calendar_data = array();

   $outputx = "";

   $entries = GFAPI::get_entries($form_id, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging, $total_count);

   foreach ($entries as $entry) {
       $idx = rgar($entry, 'id');
       $calendar_data[$idx]["fname"] = rgar($entry, '13.3');
       $calendar_data[$idx]["lname"] = rgar($entry, '13.6');
       $calendar_data[$idx]["pto_start"] = rgar($entry, '1');
       $calendar_data[$idx]["pto_end"] = rgar($entry, '3');
       $calendar_data[$idx]["e_location"] = rgar($entry, '16');
       $calendar_data[$idx]["pto_approval"] = rgar($entry, '15');

       $supervisor_location = um_user('employee_location');

       if (($supervisor_location === 'Elk City, OK') && ($e_location === 'Elk City, OK' )) {
           if ($pto_start != $this->currentDate) {
               $outputx .= '<div id="' . $this->currentDate . '" class="day ' . ($cellNumber % 7 == 1 ? ' start ' : ($cellNumber % 7 == 0 ? ' end ' : ' ')) .
               ($cellContent == null ? 'mask' : '') . '">' . $cellContent . '</div>';
           } elseif ($pto_start == $this->currentDate) {
               $outputx .= '<div id="' . $this->currentDate . '" class="day has-pto ' . ($cellNumber % 7 == 1 ? ' start ' : ($cellNumber % 7 == 0 ? ' end ' : ' ')) .
               ($cellContent == null ? 'mask' : '') . '">' . $cellContent . '<div class="inner-pto-cal ' . lcfirst($pto_approval) . '">' . $fname . ' ' . $lname . '</div></div>';
           }
       }
   }
   ```